# How to make a correct POST with http client request on ESP32 (error: "DNS Failed for sitename")

Tags: post, arduino, dns, request, esp32

I'm attempting to send a POST request to a site that I've set up, using an ESP32, containing 2 pieces of data. I have attempted to use the site "reqbin.com" to send a POST request containing the same data, so I don't think that the data itself is the issue.

Below is my code:

```
char ssid[] = "{{name}}";
char pass[] = "{{pass}}";
int port = 8080;
WiFiClient wifi;

void setup()
{
delay(1000);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF); //Prevents reconnection issue (taking too long to connect)
    delay(1000);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //This line hides the viewing of ESP as wifi hotspot

    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); //Connect to your WiFi router
    Serial.println("");

    Serial.print("Connecting");
    // Wait for connection
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }

    //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop()
{
String serverAddress = "sitename.com/data.php";
    String contentType = "text/plain"
    String postData = "t=26.1 h=25.6";
    HttpClient http = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);
    http.beginRequest(); //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.post("/", contentType, postData);
    Serial.println("httpCode = " + httpCode);
    if (httpCode > 0)
    {
        String response = http.responseBody();
        Serial.println("httpCode === " + httpCode);
        Serial.println(response);
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error on POST request");
        Serial.println(httpCode);
    }
    http.endRequest();
}
```

When using reqbin, I get a Status 200, and the site returns. However, on the ESP32, it returns the error:

```
[E][WiFiGeneric.cpp:654] hostByName(): DNS Failed for sitename.com/data.php
```

I am unsure if the syntax of my request is incorrect.

---

UPDATE: Changed my loop and changed the server address to this:

```
String serverAddress = "sitename.com";
    String contentType = "text/plain";
    String postData = "t=26.1 h=25.6";
    HttpClient http = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);
    http.beginRequest(); //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.post("/data.php", contentType, postData);
    Serial.println("httpCode = " + httpCode);
```

Now getting the error:

```
socket error on fd 57, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer"
```

Edit for Codebreaker:

```
String serverAddress = "sitename.com";
HttpClient http = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);
String response;
int statusCode = 0;

Setup has stayed the same.

void loop()
{
String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // String postData = temp + " " + humid;
    String postData = "?t=26.1&h=25.6";
    http.post("/data.php", contentType, postData);
    // read the status code and body of the response
    statusCode = http.responseStatusCode();
    response = http.responseBody();

    Serial.print("Status code: ");
    Serial.println(statusCode);
    Serial.print("Response: ");
    Serial.println(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the server expects url encoded data and not text plain. So try 
define the following before setup()

```
 int port = 80;
 String response;
int statusCode = 0;

String serverAddress = "sitename.com";
HttpClient http = HttpClient(wifi, serverAddress, port);
```

And in your loop you build the post as follows

```
String contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
String postData = "?t=26.1&h=25.6";
http.post("/data.php", contentType, postData);
```

and than read the response

```
  // read the status code and body of the response
  statusCode = http.responseStatusCode();
  response = http.responseBody();

  Serial.print("Status code: ");
  Serial.println(statusCode);
  Serial.print("Response: ");
  Serial.println(response);
```

If that works replace String class with char arrays like this

```
char serverAddress[] = "www.test.com";  // server address
```

Comment: I've made the changes you suggested and still have the error:
[E][WiFiClient.cpp:258] connect(): socket error on fd 54, errno: 104, "Connection reset by peer"
Unsure why, but it seems to happen irrespective of a lot of the changes I make.

Comment: Can you post the last version of your code its hard to hit a moving target and is it really port 8080 for http thats normally websocket so port should be 80

Comment: Going to add to main post for better formatting, 1 minute

Comment: Change port to 80

Comment: Getting a 200 response now! Think that's cracked it, cheers mate.

Comment: And watch out how to concat a post data with ?X=value&Y=value